# Jenkins not finding a nuget package

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, nuget

I'm setting a Jenkins CI server. I got the first step to run properly:

```
nuget restore -NonInteractive  -ConfigFile Nuget.config -Verbosity Detailed -NoCache
```

That works properly, but when I want to compile the app with:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

and `${WorkSpace}\src\Weather.App.csproj`
It throws this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(178,5): error : The package HockeySDK.Core with version 4.1.6 could not be found in C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyApp\Weather\Weather.App.csproj]
```

The weird thing is that it the Hockey package clearly exists in the path:
[image]

If I run the same command IN my VS2017 local project, everything runs smoothly. But the jenkins server (which is in my same machine) does not build it properly.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Any resolution on this?  We are having the exact same issue.

Comment: Hi, I got it working and if I remember properly, if you run Jenkins as service it will not default to the proper nuget folder and will go to the global one in the PC (for all users). I had to run it as a console application with the current user, so It will default to the nuget package in the current user folders. I know it's not ideal but...

Comment: I have the same problem, which started to occur when I moved from packages.config to project.json. I use Gitlab CI with runners running as system service. So if you found another solution, I'm interested to read it.

Comment: I had the very same problem with PackageReference. I "solved" it first by running the jenkins service not as a system user but a local one. Now I remorsefully go back to packages.config. I have another problem with PackageReference. It does not seem to be mature to me... :(

Comment: It's not mature. The way I work now is I use Jenkins for a couple of basic things, and then I have a WPF application listening to files being changed in a folder, from there I run my own commands and do my stuff without jenkins mingling around. Much more efficient and less headache!

Comment: Can any one help on this .   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547882/unable-to-build-nuget-packages-during-jenkins-build?noredirect=1#comment110621540_62547882

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick.

1. Put nuget.exe somewhere on he build server.
2. Ensure nuget.exe is in the PATH environment variable.
3. Restart Jenkins so that it picks up the updated PATH environment variable
4. Upgrade NuGet to the latest version

   `nuget.exe update --self`

In the Jenkins job calling rebuild against MSBUILD won't successfully restore the nuget packages

Add a Windows Batch step after the MSBUILD Clean and before the MSBUILD Rebuild like so:

`nuget restore <your_solution_file>.sln`

Path to solution file is workspace relative.

This will create the packages directory as you would expect.

Comment: I'm having a strange problem where Nuget.exe doesn't download some of the packages. Out of all packages in my project, it never downloads xunit :(

Comment: I am having same problem. Can you pl help .   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547882/unable-to-build-nuget-packages-during-jenkins-build?noredirect=1#comment110621540_62547882