# Unable to build nuget packages during Jenkins build

Tags: .net, jenkins, continuous-integration, nuget, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to build a .Net WEB API (https://github.com/NaveeenSemwal/jenkinsapi.git) using Jenkins freestyle project but i am getting error of nuget packages while building job in Jenkins. I have used VS 2019 community edition to create .net web api.

I have configured MSBuild in Jenkins as below :

[image]
Here i have configured git repository:

[image]

And this is how i am using MSBuild in Jenkins's Job :

[image]

Please find the error which i am getting while during build as below :

[image]

I have also seen in the workspace folder but didn't find any generated .DLL of that package.

[image]

Please let me know where i am missing. Thanks!

Comment: nuget restore <Path of solution file>.sln

Pass this command in Execute Windows Batch Command section in Jenkins.

Comment: Your screen shows that `MSBuild` isn't recognized. Why did you install VS Community on build server?

Comment: @RahulPandey : Can you tell me what modification in path i need to specify in 
            "C:\nuget.exe" restore JenkinsHelloWorld\JenkinsHelloWorld.sln

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski : It's not the build server. I am all doing these thing in my local machine.  MSBuild.exe exists in my local machine at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

Comment: @semwal Could you check few points
1) Set path of Nuget.exe in Environment variables
2) Once point 1 is done, then run "nuget restore <Complete_Path_Of_SolutionFile>\JenkinsHelloWorld.sln in command prompt. If that would work from command prompt, then it should also work from Jenkins.

Last, please check the UserAccount through which Jenkins Service is running. That user should have elevated permission on machine.

Comment: @RahulPandey : I have updated nuget.exe version and using command  C:\NuGet\nuget.exe restore E:\Jenkins\workspace\webapi\JenkinsHelloWorld\JenkinsHelloWorld.sln  from command prompt and its working fine but i am using same command in Jenkins job and its again giving package failre errors.

Comment: I have updated one attachment in the question.  I am able to build packages while executing    >>  C:\NuGet\nuget.exe restore "E:\Jenkins\workspace\webapi\JenkinsHelloWorld\JenkinsHelloWorld.sln"   from command prompt while in Jenkins its still giving the error.